# WPF - MVVM multiple projects structure

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I always developed application in MVVM in one project and separate Model, View, ViewModel wth folders. Looking in different questions and different books I learnt that separate them in different projects will be better for different reasons so I was trying to develop a simple project to see how it works.

Firstly I created a single project with different folders, and i start the application and it works good.
This how is the structured the "single project" I have omitted the Model folder.

[image]

After I created multiple project composed of these 3 projects:

**-MVVM**

**-MVVM.Views**

**-MVVM.ViewModels**

This how i structured the "multiple project"

[image]

I set the MVVM.Views,MVVM.ViewModels output type to Dll and not to .exe, i added the projects(MVVM.Views,MVVM.ViewModels) references in MVVM.

But when i lunch the application i get an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   WindowsBase.dll Informations: Could not locate any instances of
>   contract MVVM.ViewModels.IShell.

I'm using also *Caliburn.Micro 2.0.2* for bootstrapp and this is the MefBootstrapper:

```
public class MefBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private CompositionContainer container;

    public MefBootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
                AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()
                );

        container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        var batch = new CompositionBatch();

        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
        batch.AddExportedValue(container);

        container.Compose(batch);


        }

        protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
        {
            string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
            var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

            if (exports.Count() > 0)
                return exports.First();

            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
        {
            return container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
        }
    }
```

This is **ViewModel code**:

```
namespace MVVM.ViewModels
{
    public interface IShell { }

    [Export(typeof(IShell))]
    public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShell
    {

    }
}
```

I want to understand where i wrong? I missed one step? Thanks for support

Comment: Please provide ViewModel code. Also, having ViewModel in seperate project is disputed practice. Many WPF MVVM developers including myself consider VM as component tied to View and keep it coupled (there's even a plugin to keep ViewModel behind XAML, next to code-behind). But hey, generally you'd go MVCVM with additional Controller anyway and Controller would go to seperate project then.

Comment: I added the code. I always used the single project because is easier and fast, but reading i understand that is better keep separate the view from the viewmodel and from the model, i just want to learn also this kind but I'm not sure that in future i will use this way.

Comment: Seperating into projects is a good practice. I'm just saying that ViewModels belong to 'View' project. Model, DAL and so on should be all seperate projects.

Comment: So you say that ViewModels folder i should use into MVVM.Views project ?

Comment: I don't know sheet about CM, but I do know using reflection to load types at runtime.  If you have two assemblies in your application, A.EXE and B.DLL, and you want to load types defined in B.DLL within A.EXE, then *B.DLL MUST be loaded into the AppDomain in order to access those types*.  CM is probably looking for types in the appdomain that implement IShell, however MVVM.ViewModels isn't loaded into the executable's appdomain, and CM isn't going to load random assemblies looking for it.  Solution? There are many, not sure which is best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post the answer just in case someone will have my same problems. After reading a lot of posts and different stuff I've found the error. I forgot to load the assemblies into the application. And this is really easy just change the `Configure()` void here the code:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    string pluginPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "");
    if (!Directory.Exists(pluginPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pluginPath);

    var fi = new DirectoryInfo(pluginPath).GetFiles("*.dll");
    AssemblySource.Instance.AddRange(fi.Select(fileInfo => Assembly.LoadFrom(fileInfo.FullName)));

    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
            AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()
            );

    container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

    var batch = new CompositionBatch();

    batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
    batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
    batch.AddExportedValue(container);

    container.Compose(batch);
}
```